# Can't get AsyncTask to work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an async task to handle a whole bunch of database entries and then let the user know that the entry has been made with a textView that appends to itself. I understand that I cannot touch the views inside the `doInBackground`, but I cannot get any other methods to work. Can anyone explain to me on how to get my code to work inside of an AsyncTask?

Code:

```
private class DBADDITION extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            DBAdapter my_database = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            logout.append("\n" + "Start" + " ");
            my_database.open();
            String temp = input.getText().toString();

            int i = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                db.createEntry("example", 10 + j);
                logout.setText("\n" + j + logout.getText());

            }
            db.close();
            return "it worked";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should only be returning "it worked" in the `onPostExecute` method when all the work is actually done.

Comment: updating ui should be done on ui thread use runonuithread or an handler or update the ui onPostExecute()

Comment: When I try to return "void" it does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Account your asyctask <Object, Void, Object>, you have return a Object. You can return Void.

Answer (score 0):

```
logout.setText()
```

You can not perform operation on UI from a different Thread. All the UI Operations have to be performend on the UI thread. Since `logout` is a TextView object, you can not touch it directly from the doInBackground method, since it runs on a different Thread. YOu should use a `Handler` instance or, you have a reference to your Activity, you should call `runOnUiThread`. `runOnUiThread` allows you to post a `Runnable` on the looper queue of the `UI Thread`, without the need to instantiate an Handler.

```
final int finalJ = j;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         logout.setText("\n" + finalJ + logout.getText());
       }
 });


runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         logout.append("\n" + "Start" + " ");
       }
 });
```

Comment: Yes, logout is a textView.

Comment: Okay, this looks like it might work, but I hit one last problem. j must be set to final, but when I set it to final I can't do j++

Comment: as workaround you can assign j to a final int value. Check my edit

Comment: @blackbelt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397123/how-to-download-image-in-background-with-opengl this is a similar thread can you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onPostExecute()` method. This is automatically called after the `doInBackground()` method. Also this is on the UI thread and hence you can modify your textView here.

In case , you need to perform some UI updation before the doInBackground() then you override the `onPreExecute()` method.

Also, remove instances of any UI element updation from your `doInBackground()` like `setText()`

Answer (score 0):

You use Activity.runOnUIThread() to setText, like these:

```
private class DBADDITION extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        DBAdapter my_database = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        logout.append("\n" + "Start" + " ");
        my_database.open();


        final String temp = input.getText().toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            db.createEntry("example", 10 + j);
            youractivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     logout.setText("\n" + j + logout.getText());
                }
        );

        }
        db.close();
        return "it worked";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

}
```